# How to display an alert box after a condition is met and a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to display an alert box saying "Please input a value" when a button is clicked and there is no text in the input box. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
const checkButton = document.getElementById("check-btn");
const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

if (textInput.value = "" && checkButton.click()){
  window.alert("Please input a value")
}
```

This is not working though when i test it on freeCodeCamp's test. What am I doing wrong?

```
const checkButton = document.getElementById("check-btn");
const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

if (textInput.value = "" && checkButton.click()){
  window.alert("Please input a value")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the event listener to the button by id and check the input value within the event listener.

```
 document.getElementById('check-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let inputValue = document.getElementById("text-input").value;
    if (inputValue && inputValue.trim() === '') {
        // Display an alert if the input is empty
        alert('Please input a value');
    } else {
        // Proceed with your logic for non-empty input
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres 2 problems. So first off you can't just put `checkButton.click()` you have to put a event listener like `checkButton.addEventListener()` so it checks all the time when a button is pressed. Next, your if statement is wrong because there is supposed to be 2 equal signs not one.

```js
const checkButton = document.getElementById("check-btn");
const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
checkButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (textInput.value == ""){
    window.alert("Please input a value");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id = "text-input">
<button id = "check-btn">check</button>
```